# How to read icon / image name set for menu item in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, menu-items

```
<item
        android:title="bookmark"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_bookmark_border"
        android:id="@+id/bookmark"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

Hi, in the above code I am showing a bookmark icon in a menu item but now my requirement is to read the icon name, I am able to read or get the id of this item by using the below code

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int res_id=item.getItemId();
}
```

but I am not able to get the icon name

please help !!
thanks in advance

Comment: the output should be "ic_baseline_bookmark_border" in string formst

Answer (score 0):

please refer this article for getting more information while referring this question

https://android.i-visionblog.com/android-changing-menu-items-at-run-time-48970f0cf1b7

all thanks to **Ramkumar N**